# Rename multiple blobs inside azure storage folder using ssis

Tags: ssis, blob

My requirement is to rename the files/blob inside blob directory and change its extension in ssis. However we have to use foreach loop container to achieve the same. Also since there will be huge number of files copying and then moving will be very time taking and performance issues will arise.

I have already tried foreach azure storage blob enumerator and a file system task inside it but unable to rename.

Is there any other way to acheive the same ?